# Chrome new tab page: how to remove that promotional/marketing

Tags: windows, google-chrome, html

I'm not trying to replace the new tab page altogether. I'm just trying to remove that annoying promotional stuff. For example, it's currently saying "New! Try Bard, an early AI experiment by Google". Super evil new tab doesn't work I think.

Comment: Did you try any adblocking extension?

Comment: Hi there, extensions generally don't work on chrome:// pages and chrome also considers it very dangerous practice.

Comment: You kind of answered yourself then. As the only alternatives are changing the page (which you don't want for some unknown reason) and blocking ads on e.g. router level.

Comment: Or don't use chrome but another browser...